# Converting from NATIVE to IFRAME Sandbox with Enter Key Submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, submit, form-submit, iframe-app

I have a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815323/converting-from-native-to-iframe-sandbox) when trying to convert my apps script web app to use IFRAME Sandbox. I have converted to 'input = "button"' as suggested.

My web app is a simple form for students to use to sign in and out of a school library. The idea for the app is for it to be as easy as possible for students to use. Students should enter their id number and **be able to either click the submit button or hit the enter key**. Their ID is then validated before being stored in a spreadsheet and they get a message back saying thanks for signing in or out, or please enter a valid ID Number. Then focus should return to the text box and be cleared, ready for the next student to enter their id.

I had it working as described above using NATIVE mode. When I tried to convert it to IFRAME mode, clicking the button works, but if you hit the enter key everything just disappears and no data goes to the spreadsheet. **How can I get hitting the enter key to work the same as clicking the submit button?**

index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>
<body>
<h3>Please Sign In &amp; Out</h3>
<div id="box" class="frame">
  <form id="signSheet" onsubmit="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateInfo)
      .validateID(this.parentNode)">
    <input type="text" name="myID" id="myID" placeholder="Enter your student ID" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onmouseup="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateInfo)
      .validateID(this.parentNode)">
  </form>
  <span id="thank_you" hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?!= include('javascript'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript.html code:

```
<script>
function updateInfo(ret){

        if(ret[0]){
          $( "#thank_you" ).removeClass("error");
          $( "#thank_you" ).addClass("valid");
        }
        else{
          $( "#thank_you" ).removeClass("valid");
          $( "#thank_you" ).addClass("error");
        }
        $( "#thank_you" ).text(ret[1]);
        $( "#thank_you" ).show("slow");
        $( "#signSheet" )[0].reset();
        $( "#myID" ).focus();
        console.log(ret);
      }

</script>
```

Code.gs code:

```
//spreadsheet key is needed to access the spreadsheet.
var itemSpreadsheetKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

//Open the spreadsheet and get the sheet objects
var openedSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(itemSpreadsheetKey);
var studentList = openedSS.getSheetByName("Student List");//Spreadsheet must match with sheet name
var studentRecord = openedSS.getSheetByName("Sign In-Out Record");

function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
               .setTitle('Sign In/Out Sheet')
               .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;
}

function include(filename) {
  Logger.log('enter include');
  Logger.log(filename);
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
  Logger.log(html);
  return html;
}

function validateID(form){
  var idNum = form.myID;
  var valid = false;
  var numIdList = studentList.getLastRow()-1; //-1 is to exclude header row
  //get the item array
  var idArray = studentList.getRange(2,1,numIdList,1).getValues();
  i= idArray.length;
  while(i--){
    if(idArray[i][0]==idNum & idNum!='') {
      valid=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(valid)
    return [1, updateRecord(idNum)];
  else return [0, "ID number " + idNum + " not recognized. Please enter a valid ID number."];
}

function updateRecord(idNum){
        studentRecord.appendRow([idNum]);
        var formulas = studentRecord.getRange("B2:D2").getFormulasR1C1();
        var lRow = studentRecord.getLastRow();
        var range = studentRecord.getRange(lRow, 2, 1, 3);
        range.setFormulas(formulas);
        var vals = range.getValues();
        var now = new Date();
        studentRecord.getRange(lRow, 5, 1, 1).setValue(now);
        now = Utilities.formatDate(now, "EST", "HH:MM a");
        idNum = "Thanks " + vals[0][0] + ", you have signed " + vals[0][2] + " at " + now;
        return idNum;
  }
```

Update: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter) and added the following code to javascript.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      var idVal = $("#myID").val();
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateInfo).validateID(idVal);
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

This solved the the problem for me with a little more tweaking to parts of index.html and Code.gs

Comment: Post your answer to an answer.  Then after 2 days, mark it as correct.  That way, people looking for answers will see that this post has a correct answer.  It's not just about getting answers, it's about helping people search for answers.

Comment: Thank you, past me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter) and added the following code to javascript.html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      var idVal = $("#myID").val();
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateInfo).validateID(idVal);
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

This listens for the enter key and sends the value of the text field to the apps script function. In this case I didn't need to use `event.preventDefault();'

Then I had to adjust the button's `onmouseup` function to take `this.parentNode.myID` and change my apps script function to take a value instead of a form object.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the `<form>` tag:

Currently you have:

```
<form id="signSheet" onsubmit="google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(updateInfo)
  .validateID(this.parentNode)">
```

Change it to this:

```
<form id="signSheet">
```

You already have a call to `google.script.run` in your button, so leave that.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgot to take the `onsubmit="google.script.run..."` part out after converting it to a normal button. I don't think that part ever worked, I had just tried it out of desperation.