# Update from NATIVE sandbox to IFRAME; button not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-apps-script

Since the NATIVE sandbox on google apps script is deprecated, I'm switching to IFRAME, which has caused some issues.

The basic outline of the app is that it should allow a user to fill in some information and upload a file (it also makes sure all required fields are completed). Upon submission (by clicking a button), the file should be uploaded to a folder in google drive and a spreadsheet should be updated with the user's information. When I'm in NATIVE, everything works fine. When I set it to IFRAME, nothing happens when I click the submit button.

This is a similar issue to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815323/converting-from-native-to-iframe-sandbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358598/converting-from-native-to-iframe-sandbox-with-enter-key-submit), but neither of them directly address my problem. I also tried following the [Google Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe?utm_campaign=app%20invites_deprication_google_apps_script_101315&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) but it didn't help.

Here is my server.gs script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {

    var dropbox = "Applications";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var CV = form.CV;
    var foldername = form.myLastName + ", " + form.myFirstName;
    var myFolder = folder.createFolder(foldername);
    var file_CV = myFolder.createFile(CV);    

    var CV_url = file_CV.getUrl();

    var sheet_return = addApplicant(form, CV_url);

    return "Thank you for your submission."

  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}

function addApplicant(form, CV_url) {
  try {
    var d = new Date()
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(***INSERT URL TO GOOGLE SHEETS PAGE***);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    if (form.visa != "Yes"){
      form.visa = "No"
    }

    sheet.appendRow([d, form.myFirstName, form.myLastName, form.myEmail, form.visa, CV_url]);

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Here is my form.html script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- You can also include your own CSS styles -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">
  .warning {border: 1px solid red !important; background: #fdecb2 !important;}
  .hideClass {display:none;}
</style>


<div class="form-style-10">
<title> Application </title>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">

  <fieldset class="fields">
  <div class="section"> Personal Information </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label for="myFirstName"> First Name* </label>
    <input type="text" id="myFirstName" name="myFirstName" placeholder="" required />

    <label for="myLastName"> Last Name* </label>
    <input type="text" name="myLastName" placeholder="" required />

    <label for="myEmail"> Email* </label>
    <input type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="" required />

    <span class="visa-checkbox">
    Check if you will require visa assistance. <input type="checkbox" name="visa" value="Yes" /> 
    </span>
  </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="fields">
  <div class="section"> Documents (pdf format is preferred) </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label for="CV"> CV* </label>
    <input type="file" name="CV" required />
  </div>
  </fieldset>

  <p>  </p>
  <p id="incompleteWarning" class="hideClass"> Please check for incomplete fields and re-submit. </p>
  <p id="bePatient" class="hideClass"> Please be patient while the files are being uploaded. Do not close or refresh the form. </p>

  <input id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Submit Application" />     
</form>

<div id="output" class="hideClass">
<span id="ThankYou" >Thank you for taking the time to complete the application. 
    </span>
</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javscript">

document.getElementById('submitbutton').addEventListener("click", validatefunction);

function validatefunction() {
   document.getElementById('submitbutton').val = 'Submitting...';
   //check for required fields
   var j = 0;
   var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
   var elem = form.elements;
   for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
     elem[i].className = "";
     if (elem[i].value === "" && elem[i].hasAttribute('required')){
       elem[i].className = "warning";
       j++;
     }
   }

   if (j === 0) {
       var btn = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
       btn.disabled = true;
       document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('bePatient').style.display = 'inline';
               google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
} else{
      document.getElementById('submitbutton').val = 'Submit Application';
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.color = 'red';
    }
};

</script>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').style.display = 'inline';     
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

To:

```
<script language="javascript">
```

I don't know why it doesn't like `type="text/javscript"`

Comment: I see the issue. I didn't spell 'javascript' correctly. For some reason, NATIVE didn't care, but IFRAME did.

Comment: Oh, okay.  haha.  Thanks for letting me know, and the votes.